# What determines frequency and number of posts that are bumped by Community?

Tags: discussion, community-user, bump

I've noticed that posts that are bumped by Community follow a specific pattern. They are bumped every ~60 minutes and there are **always** 4 posts that are being bumped.

[image]

My question (purely out of curiosity) - is bumping frequency and number of posts predetermined? And why is it always 4 posts?

Comment: Some more information about bumping can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/294055). That answer doesn't explain why, though.

Comment: That post says specifically it is a maximum of 4 on SO.  Are you asking why the decision was made to make 4 the maximum?

Comment: If Community could fix the typo directly, that would bump the posts with benefits.